# Custom nspopupbutton title when using bindings and struct

Tags: macos, cocoa, timezone, cocoa-bindings, nspopupbutton

How to display timezone identifier with bindings (using structs)? e.g. instead of Africa/xxx offset 3600 i want Africa/xxx only

```
class TimezonePopupButton: NSPopUpButton {

    private var timezonesController: NSArrayController = NSArrayController()

    private var timeZones : [TimeZone] = {
        var content : [TimeZone] = []
        for identifier in TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers {
            if let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: identifier) {
                content.append(timeZone)
            }
        }
        return content
    }()

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        timezonesController.content = timeZones
        bind(.content, to: timezonesController, withKeyPath: "arrangedObjects")
        selectItem(withTitle: TimeZone.current.identifier)
    }
}
```

[image]

PS: It can be done with this hack but it looks very non swifty and i am afraid it will break in future

```
extension NSTimeZone {

    open override func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        if key == "description" {
            return self.name
        }
        return super.value(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `contentValues`

> An array of strings that are displayed as the items in the NSPopUpButton.

```
bind(.content, to: timezonesController, withKeyPath: "arrangedObjects")
bind(.contentValues, to: timezonesController, withKeyPath: "arrangedObjects.name")
```

See [NSPopUpButton Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSPopUpButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSPopUpButton-SW1).

Comment: Just a question. This works because objc runtime is NSTimezone and therefore responds to name. Is it future proof when swift TimeZone uses "identifier" (currently it crashes)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: my bad. Meaning the binding uses a struct TimeZone; this struct doesn't have "name" as property/variable. The reason why it works is because struct TimeZone is under the hood NSTimeZone with a property called "name". As objc dev I expected "identifier" variable to be bindable (which is not). I am just afraid if this code will crash with new release of macOS or swift

Comment: I think the `name` property is as future proof as using `TimeZone` with `NSArrayController` and bindings.